# external dabase connection error on EE3

Tags: xml

I have upgraded the the ee with latest license version & getting following error on the  template page where I am using external database

**this the code:**

```
$DB1 = $this->EE->load->database('XXXX', TRUE);

$query_str = 'SELECT * FROM `company` ';
$query = $DB1->query($query_str);
```

**Error:**

Notice
Undefined property: EE_Functions::$EE

ee/legacy/libraries/Functions.php(679) : eval()'d code, line 131 show details

```
Severity: E_NOTICE
```

Please reply as soon as possible

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The ExpressionEngine framework probably doesn't have a pointer reference to the namespace variable `$EE` in whatever script you're executing... to be honest, I'm guessing you copied a script example from somewhere on the net. Globally, ExpressionEngine is instantiated as a class at `ee()`. Even in (later versions, 2.5.5 and up I believe) ExpressionEngine 2.x, you would have had to declare a pointer reference in your class's namespace to have access to it like that:

```
var $EE;

function __construct ()
{
    $this->EE &= ee();
}

function whatevez_homie ()
{
    $this->EE->load->database('database_from_yonder', TRUE);
}
```

Something like that. But you needn't do that. Just use it's global declaration as a class.

```
ee()->load->database('database_from_yonder', TRUE);
```

**Quick Edit**

Oh, seeing your error, it seems as though you are already accessing the class's namespace with the magic `this`. Have you tried deleting `EE` from your statement?

```
$this->load->database('database_from_yonder', TRUE);
```